# How to Ignore files when commiting to a git repository rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, github

I am try to ignore development.rb, database.yml files when commiting to a git repository

**.gitignore**

config/environments/development.rb

config/database.yml

Comment: Just add those files to .gitignore. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please add this 2 lines in .gitignore file

```
/config/environments/development.rb
/config/database.yml
```

Comment: thank you for reply.. :)

Comment: does it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following adding `/` on the start on `.gitignore` file

```
/config/environments/development.rb
/config/application.yml
```

Here is the [.gitignore](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/gitignore) well formatting documentation.

Hope it helps